# Is a graph $G$ completely determined (up to labelling) by its spanning trees?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

The title is essentially the question. I know that trees can be represented as a topology (equivalently a topological closure operator) on a set -- so I'm wondering if the collection of spanning trees provides a "topological representation" of a graph (up to labelling of vertices).

Edit: As @dkuper pointed out a "topological" tree depends on the root --- making it more specific than a "graph" tree. I'm a topologist, not a graph theorist, so this is less interesting to me, but I think the question then essentially becomes: "Given a labelling of a graph $G$, when is $G$ the union of of its spanning trees?" A quick Google search doesn't say much, but this "seems" like a simple question.

Comment: do you put the number of times each tree appears in the collection ? If this information is lost, then the statement is false (with for instace cycle and line of same length).

Comment: The trees would retain the labelling, would that do it?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, you want to be invariant under relabelling. The question is interesting if you put each tree (up to isomorphism) in your collection, together with its multiplicity.

Comment: Basically, the different trees would be different topologies on the same set of elements. I think we need to retain some idea of how these topologies interact -- not just a count. I just mean, invariant up to coloring blue, for example. Perhaps my terminology for graph theory is not very good -- but does that make some sort of sense?

Comment: could you put a link to this topology via trees that you're referring to ?

Comment: It's very hard to find an online reference with the chaff from network topology -- I'll look on mathsci (if you can access that). The general idea is that the closure of an element of the tree $\mbox{cl}\{a\}$ is the entire chain "above" $a$. This may help: [Tree (set theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28set_theory%29).

Comment: I think the use of trees in topology is very dependent of the root, i.e. you use rooted trees. On the other hand, spanning trees are not rooted, so it could be problematic.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. The "graph tree" $a -- b -- c$ would be topologized differently depending on the root. Thanks, I might try to think of a way to make the question well-posed.

Comment: The problem of what you mean by "all spanning trees" goes beyond the root. Consider a completely connected 4 node graph. If you allow rooted trees, do you distinguish between trees with given node at root and one branch two vs the other length one, or do you just have 4 such trees overall? If you only allow one such tree per node & one w/ path of three, then you can't tell tetrahedron from square....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can extend my comment into an answer: if the collection of spanning trees includes all trees even if they are isomorphic as graphs but having different labels, then a graph isomorphism will induce an isomorphism on spanning trees and vice-versa. If you include only spanning trees up to graph isomorphism, then no, as example with tetrahedron vs cube shows (or for that matter "v" vs triangle if you disallow distinguishing spanning trees by root node).