# Is a graphs is determined by its and its complement's multiset of spanning trees?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

As shown by this post, [a graphs is not determined by its multiset of spanning trees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308058/is-a-graph-determined-by-its-multiset-of-spanning-trees).

In fact, the two graphs below have the same multiset of spanning trees, but are non-isomorphic.

[image]

Lets call such graphs *tree-equivalents*.

Notice, however, that their complements are **not** tree-equivalents. In fact the following graph appears $5$ times in the multiset of the left graph's complement, but $11$ in the multiset of the right graph's complement.

[image]

So my question is: are there two non-isomorphic tree-equivalent graphs whose complements are tree-equivalents as well?

I understand that might be a hard question, so I would also like to know what properties graphs satisfying this condition must share.

For instance, it's easy to show that the maximum degree of the graph is the maximum of the maximum degrees of it's spanning trees, so **two tree-equivalent graphs must share their maximum degrees**. If their complements are tree-equivalent as well, then that must also be true for their minimum degree.

An analogous argument can be made to prove that **two tree-equivalent graphs must share the length of its maximum path**, but I don't know if this statement implies something nice for its complements, like in the previous case.

Comment: Does the discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132728/tutte-polynomials-graph-complements-and-degree-sequences help?

Comment: @GerryMyerson the discussion linked is inspiring, but I don't see how it would help with my question in particular, since it talks about the relation between a graph and it's complement, and I wanna know about the relation between two distinct graphs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Also, the Tutte polynomial classifies spanning trees in a different way. In particular, the two graphs in this question have the same multiset of spanning trees, but different Tutte polynomials; conversely, any two $n$-vertex trees have the same Tutte polynomial, but a different multiset of spanning trees.

Comment: If the graph isn't its own complement, then the graph and its complement are two distinct graphs.