# If two graphs have same number of trees of every kind, must they be isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, graph-isomorphism

**Set-up.** Let $G$ be a (simple) graph. Given a tree $T$, let us define:
$$
a_{T}(G) = \text{number of subgraphs of } G \text{ that are isomorphic to } T
$$
If $T$ and $T'$ are isomorphic, then of course $a_{T}(G)=a_{T'}(G)$. Therefore, we only need to consider isomorphism classes of trees when defining this invariant.

**Question.** Suppose $G$ and $H$ are two graphs. Suppose that $a_{T}(G)=a_{T}(H)$ holds for **every** tree $T$. Does it follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic? *Answered in the negative by **Benjamin Baily***.

**Updated question.** Suppose $G$ and $H$ are two **connected** graphs. Suppose that $a_{T}(G)=a_{T}(H)$ holds for **every** tree $T$. Does it follow that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

**Context.** The basic invariants of $G$ are the number of vertices and the number of edges. Since vertices can be thought of trees (namely, a tree with 1 vertex) and edges can also be thought of trees (namely, a tree with 2 vertices), one is inclined to count other types of trees contained in $G$. This hopefully motivates the problem above.

**Remark.** I decided to include the tag [examples-counterexamples], just in case my question has a negative answer. If that is the case, I would love to see an explicit counterexample involving a pair of non-isomorphic graphs sharing this invariant for all trees.

Comment: Great question! My intuition tells me no, but it might take some significant computational power to locate a counterexample. I would look among cubic graphs.

Comment: This is *not* true if we are just counting spanning trees; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308058/is-a-graph-determined-by-its-multiset-of-spanning-trees?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: On the other hand, an affirmative answer to this question would imply [Harary's edge-reconstruction conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture#Formal_statements). So we shouldn't expect an easy answer to the question unless the answer is no.

Comment: @Misha Nice observations! The connection with the edge-reconstruction conjecture did not occur to me, but it makes perfect sense. The question in essence is asking for a certain refinement of that conjecture where we only delete edge-sets that results in trees.

Comment: Is this an equivalent reformulation? When we say *every* tree $T$ we need to consider only the tree subgraphs of $G$ and $H$ where each tree node is labeled with its degree in its parent graph. Suppose we have two such multisets $T_H, T_G$ for each graph respectively. Does an equivalence between the two multisets imply $G$ isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: @vvg Yes, the problem can be stated in terms of multisets. I am not sure what you mean by "labelled with its degree" though -- how does degree of a vertex come into play? The hypothesis $a_G(T)=a_H(T)$ for each tree $T$ is equivalent to saying that $G$ and $H$ share exactly the same multiset of tree subgraphs (in your notation, $T_G$ and $T_H$ would just be a sub-multisets consisting of only copies of $T$ for a particular tree $T$, so there would need to be a bijection between $T_G$ and $T_H$ as you say).

Comment: @Prism: The reason I mentioned labeling the tree nodes with the degrees is to disambiguate isomorphic unlabeled subgraph trees that are detached from different parts of a larger graph that aren't isomorphic when an edge set is added. For eg: A cube's corner unlabeled subgraph tree is isomorphic to a tetrahedron's corner unlabeled subgraph tree, but if we considered the degree-labeled subgraph trees, they can be disambiguated.

Comment: What if you assume $G$ and $H$ are connected graphs, to avoid such easy counterexamples as $G=P_3\cup P_3\cup P_3$ and $H=P_2\cup P_2\cup P_2\cup C_3$?

Comment: @Prism Could you edit the question to add the connectedness restriction as suggested?

Comment: @exfret Done!  I am grateful to Benjamin for the nice counterexample using disconnected graphs. I hope it is okay with everyone that I updated the question with the additional condition. Also, thanks to the user **MathematicsStudent1122** for adding a huge bounty to attract more attention to the question!

Comment: Let $V_k$ be the number of degree $k$ vertices, and $S_k$ the star graph with $k$ edges. Considering the relations $$2a_{S_1}=V_1+2V_2+3V_3+4V_4+\cdots$$ and for other $k$ $$a_{S_k}=\binom0kV_0+\binom1kV_1+\binom2kV_2+\binom3kV_3+\binom4kV_4+\cdots$$ (which can be solved for $V_k$ in terms of $a_{S_k}$), two graphs have the same number of star subgraphs of every kind if and only if they have the same degree sequence. That may help in searching for counterexamples.

Answer (score 10):

Counterexample:

First, note that $a_T(G_1) + a_T(G_2) = a_T(G_1\sqcup G_2)$.

Second, note that the only subtrees of cycle graphs and path graphs are paths. If $G$ is a path or cycle, the complete list of trees contained in $G$ is therefore contained in $\{P_1, \dots, P_{|V(G)|}\}.$ We can therefore identify a  cycle or path graph $G$ with a vector $v_G = (a_1,\dots, a_n)$ where $a_i = a_{P_i}(G)$ and $n = |V(G)|$. Note that $v_{P_1} = (1,0, 0), v_{P_2} = (2,1, 0),v_{P_3} = (3, 2, 1)$, $v_{C_3} = (3,3,3)$. These vectors are linearly dependent; in particular, $3v_{P_2} + v_{C_3} = 3v_{P_3}$. It follows that $P_2^{\sqcup 3}\sqcup C_3$ and $P_3^{\sqcup 3}$ have the same tree multisets, but these two graphs have a different number of connected components.

In general, more counterexamples can be constructed by considering disjoint unions of path graphs and cycle graphs, since there are $2n-2$ paths/cycles to choose from among the graphs whose only subtrees are $P_1,\dots, P_n$.

These counterexamples are completely ruined if, instead of counting subtrees, we count subforests. Perhaps this conjecture can still be proven if we consider those instead, though I do wonder whether a similar issue will arise: perhaps there are too many graphs and not enough forests for the multisets to be all distinct.

Edit: accidentally wrote $P_2$ instead of $P_3$ in a few places.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks! I've edited the post now. I just made another correction, too: there are $2n-2$ paths/cycles to choose from, not $2n-1$.

Comment: Funnily enough, I think if you consider the number of connected subgraphs of *all* types (not just trees), excluding only those isomorphic to one given connected graph $M$, then there are disconnected graphs that can "confuse" us even then. This can be shown by starting with this subgraph, adding enough of its maximal subgraphs to $H$ as disconnected components, and repeating (possibly adding subgraphs back to $G$ to balance things out) until the two graphs have the same number of connected subgraphs of all isomorphism classes except $M$.

Comment: Of course, once we restrict attention to $G$ and $H$ connected graphs, this all goes out the window.

Comment: Gave this answer the bounty as it answered the original question correctly. Thank you Benjamin!

I remain interested (along with OP) as to the connected case.

Comment: Just awarded the second bounty (+200) to this answer, as there are no other answers currently. Thank you, Benjamin!